# R: While publishing flexdashboard getting error of "Error in install.packages: unable to install packages"

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

How to publish shiny dashboard?
This is my first time and getting this error.
in system its working fine but unable to launch.

While publishing shiny app getting error of
 "Error in install.packages: unable to install packages"
in error log of app.

```
# ipak <- function(pkg) {
#   
#   new.pkg <- pkg[!(pkg %in% installed.packages()[, "Package"])]
#   if (length(new.pkg))
#     install.packages(new.pkg, dependencies = TRUE)
#   sapply(pkg, require, character.only = TRUE)}  
#
#     packages <-
#   c("flexdashboard",
#     "rmarkdown",
#     "shiny",
#     "reshape2",
#     ....
#     "rsconnect")  
#
#ipak(packages)

library(devtools)
library(flexdashboard)
library(rmarkdown)
library(reshape2)
library(shiny)
library(xlsx)
library(dplyr)
library(knitr)
library(DT)
library(rpivotTable)
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)
library(openintro)
library(highcharter)
library(ggvis)
library(rstudioapi)
library(lubridate)
library(hrbrthemes)
library(tidyr)
library(dbplyr)
library(odbc)
library(RODBC)
library(DBI)
library(htmlwidgets)
library(rsconnect)
```

After published application getting error in browser window.

```
An error has occurred. Check your logs or contact the app author for clarification.
```

error log message:

```
...    Warning in install.packages(new.pkg, dependencies = TRUE) :
...      'lib = "/opt/R/3.6.2/lib/R/library"' is not writable
...    Quitting from lines 21-132 (DashBord.rmd)
...    Warning: Error in install.packages: unable to install packages
...    152: stop
...    151: install.packages
...    150: ipak [<text>#11]
...    149: eval
...    148: eval
...    142: evaluate::evaluate
...    143: evaluate_call
...    139: block_exec
...    141: evaluate
...    138: call_block
...    137: process_group.block
...    134: process_file
...    133: knitr::knit
...    132: <Anonymous>
...    127: <reactive>
...    111: doc
...    110: shiny::renderUI
...     96: origRenderFunc
...    109: func
...     15: <Anonymous>
...      5: eval
...     95: output$__reactivedoc__
...     13: rmarkdown::run
...     12: fn
...      7: connect$retry
...      6: eval
```

Comment: it seems you have a call to `install.packages`in your Rmd file... I think it shouldn't be there. Is it for shinyapps.io?

Comment: Entire function of packeges installation is in comment, check code updated above

Comment: yes, after published in shinyapps.io app launched but getting error which i mention above.